# Is there a more efficient way to get images from the resources folder than to manually assign each image?

Tags: c#

The program I'm dealing with is a deck of cards. And right now, all the card images are assigned to the picturebox individually. (The code given is just a small part of it but you get the idea, its just a repetition till I reach the King Card).

So the way my resources are set up is like this: Clubs_1, Clubs_2, Clubs_3, etc.
I was wondering if there's a faster way than having to write this long code.

```
private void AssignCards(Card picCard, int count)
    {
        List<PictureBox> picPlayer = new List<PictureBox>() { picDealer1, picDealer2, picPlayer1, picPlayer2 };

        if (clickCount == 1)
            picPlayer.Add(picPlayer3);
        if (clickCount == 2)
        {
            picPlayer.Add(picPlayer3);
            picPlayer.Add(picPlayer4);
        }

        switch (picCard.Face)
        {
            case "Ace":
                if (count <= 1)
                    computer.Score++;
                else
                    player.Score++;

                if (picCard.Suit == "Hearts")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Hearts_1;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Diamonds")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Diamonds_1;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Clubs")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Clubs_1;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Spades")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Spades_1;
                break;
            case "Deuce":
                if (count <= 1)
                    computer.Score += 2;
                else
                    player.Score += 2;

                if (picCard.Suit == "Hearts")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Hearts_2;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Diamonds")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Diamonds_2;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Clubs")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Clubs_2;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Spades")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Spades_2;
                break;
            case "Three":
                if (count <= 1)
                    computer.Score += 3;
                else
                    player.Score += 3;

                if (picCard.Suit == "Hearts")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Hearts_3;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Diamonds")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Diamonds_3;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Clubs")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Clubs_3;
                else if (picCard.Suit == "Spades")
                    picPlayer[count].Image = Properties.Resources.Spades_3;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you do something like `Properties.Resources.Suits[picCard.Suit][1]` instead?

Comment: Boilerplate is to use *one* image, it has the card faces arranged in a 13x4 grid.  Graphics.DrawImage() overload with the two Rectangle arguments to copy the one you want.  Short from making the project resource management a lot less painful, it automatically forces you to write DRY code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look in the generated Resources.Designer.cs file. You can find it under Resources.resx in the solution explorer or you can select one of the resource names in your code and press F12 (go to definition).

The definition for one of the properties looks something like this:

```
/// <summary>
///   Looks up a localized resource of type System.Drawing.Bitmap.
/// </summary>
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap Image1 {
    get {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("Image1", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

From outside the class, you can get a resource by string name with something like this:

```
var img = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Image1", Properties.Resources.Culture);
```

You can loop through all the combinations are store a copy of each image in a lookup table rather than fetching a fresh copy each time you need it.

Comment: Im glad it works with String.Format, now I can literally access any resources. (For the people wondering what code I used):
`Image cardImage = (Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String.Format("{0}", replaceString));`

Answer (score -1):

I thik  this is best solution for you

```
                    byte[] imageArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Images/client_group_logo.png"));
                    var imageString = imageArray != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(imageArray) : "";
                    var img = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imageString);
                    ViewBag.ImagePath = img;
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP is using Winforms